# How to call a function from pythonnet clr, by knowing its C# prototype?

Tags: python, .net, pointers, clr, python.net

I have a .DLL .NET function that is documented in C# with the following prototype:

```
C# prototype  
int GroupStatusGet(string GroupName, out Int32 Status, out string errstring)
```

In another documentation it's shown as:

```
int GroupStatusGet(int SocketID,char * GroupName, int * GroupStatus)
```

I need to call it from Python with `pythonnet` / `clr`.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference(r"c:/path/to/Newport.XPS.CommandInterface.dll")
from CommandInterfaceXPS import *
xps = XPS()

xps.GroupStatusGet("MyGroup")   
# TypeError: No method matches given arguments for GroupStatusGet: (<class 'str'>)

ret, status, err = xps.GroupStatusGet("MyGroup", 0, "")  
# Works but unreliable, I sometimes get errors like:
#     "An Error has occurred during  converstion to Int32 type"
```

**If I know the C# prototype, how to call a function from pythonnet clr?**

Here in my example "out Int32 status" should be a pointer to a int32, how to pass a parameter which is a int32 pointer?

Do we just have to use a `Int32` constructor like in [Using Int32 with PythonNet in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675526/using-int32-with-pythonnet-in-python-3/50319601#50319601)?